# How can I fix "Could not find template for partial" in ractive.js?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am trying to use a component. I am already ractive components successfully, however for some reason this component just doesn't work:

```
var Ractive = require("ractive")

var log = console.log.bind(console);

var uploadComponent = Ractive.extend({
    isolated: false,
    template: 'test',
    data: {}
});

module.exports = uploadComponent;
```

Produces the error:

```
Ractive.js: Could not find template for partial "previewVideo"
```

Update: component in being used as follows:

In `myapp/index.js`

```
var previewVideo = require('component-preview-video');

new Ractive({
    el: $('.myapp-ui'),
    template: myAppTemplate,
    components: {
        previewVideo,
    ...many other components that work
    },
    oncomplete: function(){....}
},
```

In `myapp.mustache`:

```
{{>previewVideo}}
```

**How can the template be missing?** It clearly exists. Where is ractive trying to look to find it? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partials and components are different (although there's some overlap in terms of concept and functionality) – if `previewVideo` is a component, it needs to be included like so:

```html
<previewVideo/>
```

If it *is* a partial (though I'm guessing not, from the sample code) then you'd register it with Ractive via `partials` and not `components`:

```js
var previewVideo = require('component-preview-video');

new Ractive({
  el: $('.myapp-ui'),
  template: myAppTemplate,
  partials: {
    previewVideo
  },
  oncomplete: function(){....}
});
```

Comment: Erk, I'd blindly switched round the syntax for components and partials then got fixated on the template because of the error message. Thanks Rich!